# The value of this in onclick for a button

Tags: javascript, onclick, dom-events

In the code below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function foo() {
      console.log(this);
   }
  </script>
  <body>
    <button id="bar" onclick="foo()">Button</button>
    <p id="demo"></p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Why is it that when I say `onclick=foo()` on my button and `console.log(this)` in the foo function, the `this` variable is pointing to the `window`?

Since technically `onclick=foo()` is defined on the button so when the `onclick` function is called it should automatically set the value of `this` to the button correct? I know how to fix this but I never understood why this is happening.

Comment: _it should automatically set the value of this to the button correct?_  and _I know how to fix this_ IMHO its design flaw but still make question off-topic

Comment: Since if I do `onclick=foo(this)` somehow the correct context of this is passed which is the button. But in this case, `this` is pointing to the button and `this` wasn't pointing to the button in the question above.

Comment: Technically, an inline event is defined globally, jus don't use inline event handlers.

Comment: @Teemu I don't understand. If it's in the element this should point to the element correct?

Comment: You can do use `call` method and set the context of function i.e `onclick="foo.call(this)"`

Comment: @Satpal Yes I know that. I guess it calls the onclick handler in the scope of the global context.

Comment: In the element you have an attribute only, there has to be a wrapper function in the deeper implementation . Notice, that `this` refers to the element within the onclick attribute.

Comment: Cause you `foo` function is standalone with the button, at the time it was defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in my opinion it is because you did not pass your button to your function like this :

```
<input type="button" value="mybutton1" onclick="dosomething(this.value)">
```

while your code is like this:

```
<button id="bar" onclick="foo()">Button</button>
```

and the entry of your function is empty:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function foo() {
        console.log(this);
      }
    </script>
```

so you should pass this to your function like this:

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
      function foo(e) {
        console.log(e);
      }
    </script>
```

and because the value of this is not set by the call, this will default to the global object , which is window in a browser.

for more info please [check this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) out.

Answer (score 2):

In languages like Ruby or Java, `this` (or in case of Ruby `self`) will always point to the object in which your method is defined. So in Ruby if you are working on the `foo` method inside the `Bar` class, `self` will always point to the object which is the instance of the `Bar` class.

JavaScript works quite surprisingly here. Because in JavaScript function context is defined while calling the function, not while defining it! This is what can surprise many when coming to JS from different fields. Such late binding is a powerful mechanism which allows us to re-use loosely coupled functions in variety of contexts.

To answer your question, `this`, when called from an onclick event handler is executed by the global context.